# how to color a heart-shaped form I drew on Qt creator using c++

Tags: forms, qt, fill, qpainter

I have a little problem. I'm doing a video game in c++ using qt creator, and I would like to fill a form I drew in red. I colored the line but I can't find how to fill all the form. On the qt's doc, it explains how to fill a rect, and how to color a line, but I didn't find anything about how to fill a form I created. Here is the code to draw the form:

```
painter.setPen(Qt::red);
QLine line = QLine(leftPoint, bottomCenterPoint);
painter.drawLine(line);

line = QLine(bottomCenterPoint, rightPoint);
painter.drawLine(line);

line = QLine(rightPoint, topRightPoint);
painter.drawLine(line);

line = QLine(topRightPoint, centerPoint);
painter.drawLine(line);

line = QLine(centerPoint, topLeftPoint);
painter.drawLine(line);

line = QLine(topLeftPoint, leftPoint);
painter.drawLine(line);`
```

So, what should I do? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
painter.fillRect(topLeftPoint.x(), topLeftPoint.y(), width, height, Qt::red);
```

You need to find out the width and the height of your form.

Since your form is not shaped like a rectangle (you should have mentioned this in the question as it is a really important detail), you can use [`QPainterPath`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html) to define your points and then fill this path with [`QPainter::fillPath`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#fillPath). Use [`QPolygonF`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpolygonf.html) to define your shape and then add this polygon to the `QPainterPath` by using the [`QPainterPath::addPolygon`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html#addPolygon) method.

Comment: I'm using the strategy's design patern, so it won't work because the object is not a QWidget.

Comment: @GrégLoyer So what is this form if it's not a `QWidget`?

Comment: It's a form that I'm drawing myself. I'm defining the points, like that:

    newPointX = pos.x()+size/2;
    newPointY = pos.y() + size;
    QPoint bottomCenterPoint = QPoint(newPointX*xRatio, newPointY*yRatio);

And the I draw from point to point with the code i show you in the question

Comment: @GrégLoyer Edit your question and put the details in it.

Comment: @GrégLoyer I edited my answer based on the information you added.

Comment: my form is a heart, not a rectangle. So, maybe i'm wrong but I don't think it will work :(

Comment: @GrégLoyer Edited answer. You sure left out a lot of important details from your question.